# Understanding output of the seq function

Tags: r, na, seq

When using the seq function, I get the following outputs:

```
>seq(1,4)
1 2 3 4
```

and this retrieves the second element from the sequence

```
>seq(1,4) [2]
2
```

These two I understand. However, I don't understand why the following yields four NA values

```
>seq(1,4) [NA]
NA NA NA NA
```

But the below example does not initiate four "ABC" values instead just one NA

```
>seq(1,4) ["ABC"]
NA
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

What is important here is that `NA` is logical:

```
class(NA)
## [1] "logical"
```

and logical indexes always get recycled.

```
seq(1, 4)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
## [1] 1 3
```

If you use an integer NA then this won't happen:

```
seq(1, 4)[NA_integer_]
## [1] NA
```

Comment: thanks, this makes sense. so when I type seq(1,4)[NA]. So NA is being recycled and referenced with the sequence all four times. Lastly, what is the logic behind returning NA when that reference happens?

Comment: In general basic operations that involve an NA as one of the arguments return NA unless the result would be the same whatever value the NA might represent.  NA^0 is 1 and TRUE|NA is TRUE but 3[NA] is unknown.

Comment: Awesome start to my Saturday. Mucho gracias!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with seq function. If you try to subset values using NA, you get back a vector of NAs.

```
a <- c(1, 2)
a[NA]
```